# If $A$ is a square matrix and $A^2 = 0$ then $A=0$. Is this true? If not, provide a counter-example.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples, nilpotence

This is a proof question and I am not sure how to prove it. It is obviously true if you start with $A = 0$ and square it.

I was thinking:

If $ A^2 = 0 $

then
$ A A = 0 $

$ A A A^{-1} = 0 A^{-1}$

$I\,A = 0 $

but the zero matrix is not invertible and that it was not among the given conditions.

Where's a good place to start?

Comment: Hint: Nilpotent matrices.

Comment: You were not given that $A$ is invertible, so $A^{-1}$ may not make sense.  In fact, $A^2=0$ proves it is not invertible, because the deteminant of $A^2$ is the square of the determinant of $A$, so the determinant of $A$ is zero.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**HINT**: Consider $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 4):

Given two nonzero orthogonal vectors $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $A = vu^T$, then

$$
A^2 = vu^Tvu^T = 0
$$

Answer (score 3):

consider
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\
-4 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$