# Let $K$ be a field and $A \in K^{n \times n}$, $A^2=0$. Show that $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq \frac{n}{2}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $K$ be a field and $A \in K^{n \times n}$, $A^2=0$.
Show that $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq \frac{n}{2}$.

I have found similar posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239281/if-a-matrix-a-square-is-0-does-it-follow-that-a-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236230/if-a-is-a-square-matrix-and-a2-0-then-a-0-is-this-true-if-not-provid). 
Unfortunately it is still not clear to me how to solve that task.
Can someone help me to find the correct proof?

What I have tried:

It seems like A is nilpotent.

If $A^2=0$ then $\det(A^2)=0$.
Because $\det(A \cdot B) = \det(A) \cdot \det(B)$ it follows that:

$\det(A^2)=\det(A) \cdot \det(A) \Rightarrow \det(A)=0$.

$\Rightarrow \chi_A = \det(A - X \cdot E_n) = X^n$

$\Rightarrow A$ has Eigenvalue $0$ (n times).

$\Rightarrow A$ has a $n$-dimensional kernel.

$\Rightarrow$ by nullity theorem: $rank(A)=0 \leq \frac{n}{2}$.

Which is wrong. Counterexample:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441116/if-a-is-an-n-times-n-matrix-and-a2-0-then-textranka-le-n-2 instead.

Comment: I don't see how $\chi_A=X^n$ follows. And if it's true that $A$ has an eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n$ it does not follow that the kernel has dimension $n$. The geometric multiplicity is less than _or equal to_ the algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: Hint: Say the rank is $r$. The rank-nullity equation shows the dimension of the nullspace is $n-r$. Now if $r>n/2$ then $r>n-r$, so the image cannot be contained in the nullspace...